# Actualizacion labels en C#

Tags: c#

tengo un pequeño problemilla a la hora de hacer click en una celda de un grid que muestra una base de datos

A la hora de hacer click en la celda debe actualizar unos lbl pero no los actualiza al mismo tiempo... al darle un click me actualiza solo el label3 y tengo que darle un segundo click para que actualice el label4

```
private void DataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewRow fila = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            label3.Text = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells[5].Value);
            txtid.Text = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells[0].Value);
            txtacreditacion.Text = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells[5].Value);
            label4.Text = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells[7].Value);

        }
```

Tengo otra instruccion despues que cuando cambia el label 4 si ya tiene info al seleccionar la celda esconda un txt

```
private void label4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  if (label4.Text != "") { 
      txts.Visible = false; 
  } 
  else { 
   txts.Visible = true;    
  } 
}
```

Comment: Se ejecuta alguna otra cosa que pueda provocar el cambio del label4 y que no hagas que veas el cambio automaticamente? el codigo esta bien

Comment: private void label4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (label4.Text != "")
            {
                txts.Visible = false;
            }

            else
            {
                txts.Visible = true;

            }
        }

Comment: Tengo otra instruccion despues que cuando cambia el label 4 si ya tiene info al seleccionar la celda esconda un txt

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y agrega todo eso a la pregunta.. esas cosas son las que te estan molestando

Comment: Esta bastante raro lo que mencionas que debes presionar una segunda vez para ver el valor en el label4, o al menos esta raro con el codigo que nos proporcionas. Salvo en el CellClick del grid y en el TextChanged del propio label4 son los lugares donde accedes a este label, no hay ningun otor lugar en el codigo ?

Comment: si es el unico lugar donde tengo el label

Answer (score 0):

Al final del evento DataGridView1_CellClick agrega la instrucción:

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

No abuses de este metodo ya que puede disminuir el rendimiento de la aplicación

Comment: lo agregue despues del label4.Text = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells[7].Value);
pero sigue pasando lo mismo

Comment: En realidad, esto es para que la app ejecute eventos mientras esta ocupada haciendo otras cosas.. no deberia ser el caso..

Comment: No veo que el DoEvents aplique en este caso, se supone que si tienes un proceso que bloquea el thread de la aplicaicon impide que se actualice la UI por eso usarias el DoEvents para devolverle el control y refresque, pero en este caso no hay nada tan pesado en proceso que produzca este efecto